# Should I write an implementation of a custom element whithin <body>?

Tags: javascript, html, import, web-component

Like the below code, the implementation of a custom element is imported.
And is naked, which means, the imported document has no body and head.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="import" href="html/demo-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <demo-element>hello world</demo-element>
</body>
</html>
```

**demo-element.html**

```
<template>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        background-color: #F2CEE5;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>

    <div>
        <content></content>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var thisDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
        createdCallback: {
            value: function() {
                var t = thisDoc.querySelector('template');
                var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
                this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
            }
        }
    });
    var element = document.registerElement('demo-element', {
        prototype: proto
    });
})();
</script>
```

I want you see the below which is the result which chrome dev tool shows.
The imported document has head and body and **the implementation is in head somehow**.
I want to know if this is common or I should write head and body in demo-element.html and put the implementation in the body.

[image]